# In $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ is the median and....

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ is the median and $P$ is a point on $AD$ such that $AP:PD=1:2$. Prove that $AR(6\triangle ABP)=AR(\triangle ABC)$.
[image]

My Attempt :

Since $AD$ is the median

$\triangle ABD=\triangle ADC=\frac{1}{2} \triangle ABC$

Also,

$\frac {AP}{PD}=\frac {1}{2}=k(let)$

So,

$AP=k, PD=2k$

Now,  what should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $\frac{AM}{MC}=\frac mn$. Then $$\frac{S_{AMX}}{S_{CMX}}=\frac{\frac12AM\cdot XD}{\frac12 MC \cdot XD}=\frac{AM}{MC}=\frac mn$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let **[ABC]** denote the **area** of $\Delta ABC$

[image: The Reference Picture]

Now let $G$ be the centroid. So $AP=PG=GD$

Area of two triangles can be written as the ratio of their bases when they share a common altitude which is the case in this problem. Now as $BD=CD$, so,

$\frac{[ABD]}{[ADC]} =\frac{BD}{DC} = 1$

Similarly, [PBD]=[PDC] and [GBD]=[GDC]

Thus, [APB]=[APC] , [BPG]=[CGP]

Now drop a perpendicular from $B$ to $PD$. Note that $\Delta BGP$ and$\Delta BGD$ thus have equal altitude and share equal base. Thus, $[BGP]=[BGD]$
On similar application we will obtain

**[APB]=[APC]=[GBD]=[GDC]=[BPG]=[CGP]**

Thus

$$\boxed{6[ABP]=[ABC]}$$

Proved!

---